# Shiurim in depth on Basar VeChalav and Ta'aruvos

Tags: meat-and-milk, shulchan-aruch, adult-learning, contemporary-halacha

Does anyone have any recommendations for in depth Shiurim on Hilchos Basar VeChalav and Ta'aruvos in Shulchan Aruch.

I am looking for a shiur which will go through the Shluchan Aruch, Shach, Taz and the other major Acharonim and discuss them even if we don't generally follow their ruling and also the Halacha L'maaseh, the practical Halacha which comes out.

Please do not suggest shiurim which are only practical halacha or just go through the Shulchan Aruch without discussing the Halcha L'maaseh.

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/search/?category=0,234100

Comment: http://www.mp3shiur.com/viewProd.asp?catID=99

Comment: http://www.mp3shiur.com/viewProd.asp?catID=99